# Selenium WebDriver - Disable Native Events (Enable Synthesized Events)

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium (WebDriver), depending on OS, the Firefox Driver uses "native events" for user interaction simulation (keyboard, mouse, etc).  It can also use "synthesized events", user interaction emulated via Javascript.

How do I disable native events, and enable synthesized events? (in Python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a Firefox profile, you can set a preference or property like this (both have same effect):

```
profile.native_events_enabled = False
```

or...

```
profile.set_preference('webdriver_enable_native_events', False)
```

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.native_events_enabled = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
# synthesized events are now enabled for this 
# driver instance... native events are disabled.
...
```